# How do you toggle showing the results tab in SSMS query editor

Tags: ssms-2012

In the previous version the shortcut key was

Ctrl+R

This would close or open the query results pane in previous versions of SSMS, but in SSMS2012 that doesn't work anymore.  This was a nice way for me to get extra screen real-estate while building sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue at work.
This fixed the problem http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2860024#MT2